# Google Sheets - referencing data from another sheet "DataSheet!A1:A" want to be able to import a new sheet and update that reference... best way?

Tags: google-sheets, reference, google-sheets-formula

I'm not well-versed in Google Sheets or anything related to it really, but i'm doing basic google sheet formula stuff at the moment for my business, I am importing data from somewhere else and have copied over data from the import into my stats sheet using the basic copy formula

"DataSheet!A1:A"

later on, the Data Sheet will have to be updated with another imported sheet that will match in rows/columns but with new values...

... How do I reference/copy over columns from another sheet, while making it easy to update with a new import later on?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try:

```
={DataSheet!A1:A; DataSheet2!A1:A}
```